#  MPMoviePlayerController not rotating views when in fullscreen mode

Tags: mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen, uisplitviewcontroller, ios5.1, layoutsubviews

I am currently working on a masterDetail app for iPad iOS 5.1.

when a row is tapped in the masterViewController, a video is played in the detail view controller. The video plays fine and can be rotated when in full screen mode.

However, when the device is rotated whilst the video is in fullscreen mode, it does not rotate the underlying views. As a result when the video exits fullscreen the underlying views flicker to the previous orientation, for a split second, before changing to the current orientation.

I have tried capturing the MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullScreen notification, and then calling shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation.....but this has not helped.

I also get the following error when I enter fullscreen mode:

"Split view controller  should have its children set before layout!". however this error only occurs in the simulator.

Could anyone please shed some light on this issue?